# Como injetar conteúdo em texto copiado da página

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber como se faz para injetar conteúdo em texto copiado da página. Quando copiei  um texto de um site, ele veio junto com um texto institucional e o link do site. Vocês podem ver isso acontecendo [neste site](http://www.dino.com.br/releases/aplicativo-bmj-best-practice-e-sucesso-e-sera-lancado-em-portugues-dino89043528131).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazeres isso tens de adicionar um event handler para o evento `copy`.

Dentro desse handler tens de ir buscar o texto já selecionado e depois juntar a parte nova.

Exemplo:

```
function addLink(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var copyright = ' - Ler mais aqui: www.google.com';
    var novoTexto = copytext = window.getSelection() + copyright;
    (window.clipboardData ? window : event).clipboardData.setData('Text', copytext);
}

window.addEventListener('copy', addLink);
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wq6egLL9/

Em alguns browsers o `clipboardData` é uma propriedade do `event`, no IE é uma propriedade da `window`, daí o teste `window.clipboardData ? window : event`

Comment: Nossa Perfeito muito obrigado

Comment: Tem um grande portal de notícias aqui do Brasil que faz isso, substituindo o texto copiado com uma aviso + link para a postagem. É extremamente irritante, principalmente quando você só quer copiar uma frase.

Comment: Sergio, como rodar esse exemplo no Firefox? Funcionou no chrome e IE aqui.

Comment: Isso é muito bom pra proteger conteúdo